# Tableview odd behaviour during scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an tableview which contains 30 no of fields(label,textfield,star rating,and some other UIView,picercontrol).the problem is that when i scroll the table view the cells are getting replaced .any solution for this?
EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReuseCell";
   // UIColor* mainColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:43.0/255 green:128.0/255 blue:191.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        if (indexPath.section==0) {

            if (indexPath.row==0) {
                productImage=[self createImageWithFrame: CGRectMake(115.5, 10, 89,89)];
                productImage.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;
                [cell.contentView addSubview: productImage];
            }
            else{
                titleLabel1=[self createLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 100, 30)];////normal label
                titleLabel1.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];
                titleLabel1.text=[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
                if (indexPath.row==2) {
                productImage=[self createImageWithFrame: CGRectMake(104, 10, 190,20)];
                productImage.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;;
                [cell.contentView addSubview: productImage];

                }
               else if (indexPath.row==7) {
                titleLabel1=[self createLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 100, 30)];////time label
                titleLabel1.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;
               [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];
                }
               else if (indexPath.row==8) {
                titleLabel1=[self createLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 100, 30)];///time label
                titleLabel1.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;
               [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];
                }
              else  if (indexPath.row==9) {
                    descriptionText=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(104, 10, 190, 50)];
                    descriptionText.tag =indexPath.row+indexPath.section;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:descriptionText];
                }
              else{
                textFld=[self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectMake(104, 10, 190, 20)];
                textFld.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:textFld];
                  textFld.text=[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
              }
            }

        }
    }

    ///////trying to resuse the cell
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        if (indexPath.row==0) {
            productImage=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section];
            //productImage.image=
        }
        else{
            titleLabel1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section];
            titleLabel1.text=[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+indexPath.section-1];
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
               // productImage=[self createImageWithFrame: CGRectMake(104, 10, 190,20)];


            }
            if (indexPath.row==7) {
              // titleLabel1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section];////time label


            }
            if (indexPath.row==8) {
              // titleLabel1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section];;///time label


            }
         //   textFld=(UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section];

            if (indexPath.row==9) {

            }
        }

    }
```

Edit:leave for 7 section for 1 section:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReuseCell";
   // UIColor* mainColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:43.0/255 green:128.0/255 blue:191.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.tag=indexPath.row;
        if (indexPath.row!=0) {
            titleLabel1=[self createLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 100, 30)];
            titleLabel1.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];

        }
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    }
    else{
        titleLabel1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section];
    }
    if (indexPath.row!=0) 
         titleLabel1.text=[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+indexPath.section-1];
      return cell;
}
and my labelArray is:
 labelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"*Name",@"Category",@"Brand",@"Model",@"Serial no",@"Bill no",@"*Purchase date",@"*Expiry Date",@"Description",nil];
```

Comment: How many sections do you have in UITableview

Comment: possible duplicate of [UItableViewCell Repeating when scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063022/uitableviewcell-repeating-when-scroll) - Never ever duplicate your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to in proper tagging of views inside the cell. In your implementation first row of zeroth section and zeroth row of first section will be tagged with same number.

You should tag the views by below way:

```
productImage.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section*1000;
```

Retrieve them by same way:

```
productImage=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section*1000];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in setting the tag value:
use `indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999(some value);`

Try This:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReuseCell";
   // UIColor* mainColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:43.0/255 green:128.0/255 blue:191.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        if (indexPath.section==0) {

            if (indexPath.row==0) {
                productImage=[self createImageWithFrame: CGRectMake(115.5, 10, 89,89)];
                productImage.tag=indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;
                [cell.contentView addSubview: productImage];
            }
            else{
                titleLabel1=[self createLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 100, 30)];////normal label
                titleLabel1.tag=indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];
                titleLabel1.text=[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
                if (indexPath.row==2) {
                productImage=[self createImageWithFrame: CGRectMake(104, 10, 190,20)];
                productImage.tag=indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;;
                [cell.contentView addSubview: productImage];

                }
               else if (indexPath.row==7) {
                titleLabel1=[self createLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 100, 30)];////time label
                titleLabel1.tag=indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;
               [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];
                }
               else if (indexPath.row==8) {
                titleLabel1=[self createLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 100, 30)];///time label
                titleLabel1.tag=indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;
               [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel1];
                }
              else  if (indexPath.row==9) {
                    descriptionText=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(104, 10, 190, 50)];
                    descriptionText.tag =indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:descriptionText];
                }
              else{
                textFld=[self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectMake(104, 10, 190, 20)];
                textFld.tag=indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:textFld];
                  textFld.text=[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*indexPath.section-1];//check this line I dont have idea about your array.
              }
            }

        }
    }

    ///////trying to resuse the cell
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        if (indexPath.row==0) {
            productImage=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;];
            //productImage.image=
        }
        else{
            titleLabel1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;];
            titleLabel1.text=[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+indexPath.section-1];
            if (indexPath.row==2) {
               // productImage=[self createImageWithFrame: CGRectMake(104, 10, 190,20)];


            }
            if (indexPath.row==7) {
              // titleLabel1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;];////time label


            }
            if (indexPath.row==8) {
              // titleLabel1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;];;///time label


            }
         //   textFld=(UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row*indexPath.section+9999;];

            if (indexPath.row==9) {

            }
        }

    }
```

You missed : `return cell;`

Answer (score 0):

when you scroll your table view then that corresponding cell internally calls reload method . To avoid this you should use reusable cell :

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: but the problem is that how to retrive the cell content